# Is a person allowed to wear tefillin during Tish'a B'Av Shacaharit if he won't be able to daven mincha that day?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, tisha-bav

Let's say a person needs surgery on Tish'a B'Av in the afternoon. He knows that he will not be able to daven Mincha.

Should he wear *tefillin* during *Shacharit* instead? What if he attends shul for *Shacahrit* where no one else will be wearing *tefillin*? Would that cause problems such as *mar'it ayin*? If that's not OK, should he daven in shul without the *tefillin*, then when he returns home, put them on?

Comment: Not everyone doesn't wear Tefillin Tisha B'Av morning, fwiw, and those that don't are just following a custom, so seemingly he should wear them at some point after dawn before surgery.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt The Gra put them on right after Kinnot even before Chatzot (Maaseh Rav 200) and the Beer Heitev (555) quotes rabbis who would wear them and say Kriat Shema before going to Shul for Shacharit. Many Israeli Sefardim wear them at Shacharit until just before Kinot (see Sefer Eretz Yisrael of RYMT).