# Tefillin at chatzos on Tisha BAv

Tags: minhag, tefilin, mourning-aveilus, tisha-bav, mincha-afternoon-prayer

The general practice is to [not wear tefillin in the morning on Tisha BAv](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84507/1739) ([OC 555:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.555.1)). However, after chatzos many of the mourning practices which are only customs are lifted. As such, people wear tefillin at Mincha (see Mishnah Berurah [ad. loc.](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.555.3)).

However, I have seen many congregations that delay Mincha until the end of the fast. As a result, they delay putting on tefillin until then. My impression is they don't put them on earlier at home. But, why not? There's a concept of זריזים מקדימים למצוות, the alacritous perform Mitzvos at the earliest opportunity (see for example [Pesachim 4a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.4a.6)). Why is the general practice to wait until  even a late Mincha? I could see the idea that it's better to pray with tefillin on, but why not put them on earlier? Or enforce Mincha Gedolah?

Comment: People are at work and can only come later (or aren't willing to come back a second time for Maariv later). That's life. I don't see much reason to think the answer to this isn't אין הכי נמי put em on earlier [too] if you can. Do you? If so, please edit it in

Comment: @DoubleAA not as of yet, and I'm wondering why not, or why no one else does. I see your point about coming back to shul twice, but Tisha BAv falls on Sunday quite regularly so work shouldn't be a factor. I'd still say (unless I'm missing something) why not put on at home/work earlier.

Comment: Who says no one does? Nothing I said above was an endorsement. I don't understand why you think there's a reason here to be found. People aren't around and/or don't think about it. The phenomenon is entirely explained and understood using just "people don't think to" and "it's often inconvenient"

Comment: @DoubleAA so then you can change to question to be on the shul rabbanim or the gabbai why they don't teach/recommend/remind people to do so when they schedule Mincha late. No one says no one does but that's my impression. I'm sure if I took a poll the results wouldn't shock me.

Comment: As an aside-more reason not to procrastinate-one should probably should not nap and for those that are not fasting (age,health) probably should not eat until after donning teflin on תִשְׁעָה בְּאָב.

Answer (score 4):

The [Shulchan Aruch (558:1)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=66) mentions that the Beth HaMikdash was set on fire towards the evening of the 9th and burnt until sunset the next day.

> **א** בְּתִשְׁעָה בְּאָב לְעֵת עֶרֶב הִצִּיתוּ אֵשׁ בַּהֵיכָל וְנִשְׂרַף עַד שְׁקִיעַת הַחַמָּה בְּיוֹם עֲשִׂירִי

In the Shulchan Aruch [555](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=64) the Mishna Berura explains in the name of the Vilna Gaon that the reason we put on Tefillin at Mincha is that once the Mikdash was set alight, the *sin was eradicated* by Gcd's wrath being spent on the wood and stones.

> **ובמנחה**. שאז הציתו אש במקדש ותם עונך במה ששפך הקב"ה חמתו בעצים ואבנים [הגר״א] ‏

Since, as we saw, the fire was started late afternoon, it makes sense to delay the Mincha service as long as possible.

Comment: Interesting that you quote the Gra, when the Gra himself reportedly put on tefillin on Tisha B'Av, as soon as he finished saying Kinnos, even BEFORE "chatzos" (Ma'aseh Rav, 200).

Comment: @IsraelReader - I didn't quote the Gra, the Chafets Chaim did, probably based on the Hag' HaGra on Shulchan I would guess. (And this is not the first time it would contradict a Maaseh Rav.)

Comment: When is לעת ערב? Already at Mincha Gedolah they would offer the קרבן תמיד של בין הערביים. Why do you say the fire started in late afternoon?

Comment: Do those with this custom similarly avoid working and sitting on chairs until late in the afternoon? If not, that throws a wrench in your explanation. (Yours, not the Mishna Berura's, since the MB didn't say anything about late in the afternoon specifically being better or something.)

Comment: @DoubleAA - E.g. Eicha 1:2 רש"י  בכו תבכה בלילה. שהמקדש נשרף בלילה דאמר מר לעת ערב הציתו בו את האור, - Similar: Zecharia 14:7 מצודת דוד: לעת ערב. סמוך לערב יהיה אור, While Rashi in Yirmiya 6:4 supports your objection קַדְּשׁוּ עָלֶיהָ מִלְחָמָה קוּמוּ וְנַעֲלֶה בַצָּהֳרָיִם אוֹי לָנוּ כִּי פָנָה הַיּוֹם כִּי יִנָּטוּ צִלְלֵי עָרֶב:  רש"י   כי פנה היום. כאשר פנה לעת ערב הציתו האור בבה''מ - makes it seem like early afternoon. The Metzudoth argues.